# Error: missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.v1.DeploymentSpec (error despite including 'selector' in the yaml file)

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops

I ran into the above stated error and the most popular answer for this error is adding 'selector:' to the yaml file. I get this error even after adding it. Can you please help me rectify this issue?

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sampleapp
  labels:
    app: sampleapp
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
        app: sampleapp
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
      labels:
        app: sampleapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sampleapp
        #replace <foobar> with your container registry. Example: contosodemo.azurecr.io
        image: containerregistrycanary.azurecr.io/azure-pipelines-canary-k8s
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
        - containerPort: 8080
```

fortio.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fortio
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fortio
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fortio
        image: fortio/fortio:latest_release
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http-fortio
        - containerPort: 8079
          name: grpc-ping
```

servicemonitor.yml

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: sampleapp
  labels:
    release: sampleapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sampleapp
  endpoints:
  - port: metrics
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add selection rules to your `selector` in the *fortio.yml*, e.q.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fortio
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
       app: fortio
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fortio
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fortio
        image: fortio/fortio:latest_release
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http-fortio
        - containerPort: 8079
          name: grpc-ping
```

> The .spec.selector field defines how the Deployment finds which Pods
> to manage. In this case, you select a label that is defined in the Pod
> template (app: nginx). However, more sophisticated selection rules are
> possible, as long as the Pod template itself satisfies the rule.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment